# I want to output a pandas dataframe to a json file in a specific way

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-conversion

So this is my dataframe

```
                                               name_course  teacher  courseAverage
student_id name_student totalAverage course_id                                    
1          A            72.033333    1             Biology    Mr. D           90.1
                                     2             History   Mrs. P           51.8
                                     3                Math   Mrs. C           74.2
2          B            62.150000    1             Biology    Mr. D           50.1
                                     3                Math   Mrs. C           74.2
3          C            72.033333    1             Biology    Mr. D           90.1
                                     2             History   Mrs. P           51.8
                                     3                Math   Mrs. C           74.2
```

i used

```
with open(sys.argv[5], 'w') as f:
    f.write(maindf.to_json())
```

sys.argv[5] being output.json. This is the output I got

```
{"name_course":{"(1, 'A', 72.03333333333333, 1)":"Biology","(1, 'A', 72.03333333333333, 2)":"History","(1, 'A', 72.03333333333333, 3)":"Math","(2, 'B', 62.15, 1)":"Biology","(2, 'B', 62.15, 3)":"Math","(3, 'C', 72.03333333333333, 1)":"Biology","(3, 'C', 72.03333333333333, 2)":"History","(3, 'C', 72.03333333333333, 3)":"Math"},"teacher":{"(1, 'A', 72.03333333333333, 1)":"Mr. D","(1, 'A', 72.03333333333333, 2)":" Mrs. P","(1, 'A', 72.03333333333333, 3)":" Mrs. C","(2, 'B', 62.15, 1)":"Mr. D","(2, 'B', 62.15, 3)":" Mrs. C","(3, 'C', 72.03333333333333, 1)":"Mr. D","(3, 'C', 72.03333333333333, 2)":" Mrs. P","(3, 'C', 72.03333333333333, 3)":" Mrs. C"},"courseAverage":{"(1, 'A', 72.03333333333333, 1)":90.1,"(1, 'A', 72.03333333333333, 2)":51.8,"(1, 'A', 72.03333333333333, 3)":74.2,"(2, 'B', 62.15, 1)":50.1,"(2, 'B', 62.15, 3)":74.2,"(3, 'C', 72.03333333333333, 1)":90.1,"(3, 'C', 72.03333333333333, 2)":51.8,"(3, 'C', 72.03333333333333, 3)":74.2}}
```

This is the output I want

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "A",
      "totalAverage": 72.03,
      "courses": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Biology",
          "teacher": "Mr. D",
          "courseAverage": 90.1
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Math",
          "teacher": "Mrs. C",
          "courseAverage": 74.2
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "History",
          "teacher": "Mrs. P",
          "courseAverage": 51.8
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "B",
      "totalAverage": 62.15,
      "courses": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Biology",
          "teacher": "Mr. D",
          "courseAverage": 50.1
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Math",
          "teacher": "Mrs. C",
          "courseAverage": 74.2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "C",
      "totalAverage": 72.03,
      "courses": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Biology",
          "teacher": "Mr. D",
          "courseAverage": 90.1
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "History",
          "teacher": "Mrs. P",
          "courseAverage": 51.8
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Math",
          "teacher": "Mrs. C",
          "courseAverage": 74.2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I manipulated multiple dataframes, calculated course average based on test weights, then calculate the total average based on course averages, and then merged and reordered to set up the dataframe in the exact format the json file looks like. I thought it would be easily converted after all of that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pandas `to_json` can accept additional parameters, check them out.

Answer (score 1):

You must use orient="records".

```
maindf.to_json(orient="records")
```

or

```
maindf.to_json(orient="columns")
```

Comment: You need to make a special function for this. like this;
def function(x):
    # your logic
  return x
maindf_result = maindf.apply(function)